# I need to parse the XML file in my android application. I dont know how many nodes it got 

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing

My activity class look like this:

```
AssetManager assetmgr= getAssets();         
String list[] = assetmgr.list("subdir");    

if (list != null) {
    DocumentBuilder builder =DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(getAssets().open("subdir/fullSurvey.xml"));
```

xml object class looks like this:

```
NodeList root = doc.getElementsByTagName("root");
NodeList nlQuestions = root.item(0).getChildNodes();

QuestionObject[] allQuestions = new QuestionObject[nlQuestions.getLength()];

for (int i = 0; i < nlQuestions.getLength(); i++) {
    Node question =  nlQuestions.item(i);
    NodeList childNodes = question.getChildNodes();

    QuestionObject x = new QuestionObject();

    for (int j = 0; j < childNodes.getLength(); j++) {
        Node child =  childNodes.item(j);               

        if (child.getNodeName() !="#text") {
            Questions t = Questions.valueOf(child.getNodeName());
            // etc.
```

I dont know how to parse xml file according to attribute value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know that many XML parsers will traverse according to attribute values. Most deal with nodes, nodelists, etc. You may have to read in all the nodes and hash by the attribute values yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I got attribute value through Xpath dynamically.DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
  StringWriter xmlAsWriter = new StringWriter();
  StreamResult result = new StreamResult(xmlAsWriter);
  TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(source, result);
  StringReader xmlReader = new StringReader(xmlAsWriter.toString());
  InputSource inputSrc = new InputSource(xmlReader);